# sort, add and delete similar index of list of dictionary, using FIFO

Tags: python, dictionary, inventory-management

I am trying to solve this, and I have got the list of dictionary something like this. (This is the dictionary from 'purchase method')

```
[{'qty': 20, 'price': 2000.0, 'product': 'Computer', 'date': '2017-03-05'}, 
{'qty': 22, 'price': 5000.0, 'product': 'Computer', 'date': '2017-11-11'},
{'qty': 6, 'price': 1523.0, 'product': 'Computer', 'date': '2018-02-03'},
{'qty': 10, 'price': 1000.0, 'product': 'Computer', 'date': '2018-12-05'},
{'qty': 20, 'price': 2000.0, 'product': 'Computer', 'date': '2019-11-06'},
{'qty': 10, 'price': 1000.0, 'product': 'Computer', 'date': '2019-08-02'}
]
```

I am trying create a method called `def sale(quantity, date):` In this function, I want to pass in quantity and date, if enough stock is available before sale date, it allows me to sale that amount of quantity.

e.g. if I pass quantity = 30 and date = 2018-01-01 , it should allow me to sell because it is possible to sell due to enough quantity, and after this, remaining quantity and price should be calculated according and should be added to the above list of dictionary.

eg. in our case

```
{'qty': 12, 'price': 2000.0, 'product': 'Computer', 'date': '2018-01-01'}
```

and the first 2 dictionary should be deleted, because we already sold them!
(this is like inventory FIFO thing)

Here's my code that i am trying to do this. However, I'm getting errors and I'm not getting my desired output. Any other possibilities? How do I make it work?

```
import datetime
from collections import Counter

class Supplier:
    def add_supplier(self, name, address, email, contact_no):
        self.name = name
        self.address = address
        self.email = email
        self.contact_no = contact_no

class Product:
    def add_product(self, name):
    self.name = name

class Company(Supplier, Product):
    data_dict = []
    def purchase(self, product_obj, qty, price, date=datetime.date.today()):
    self.data_dict.append({'product': product_obj.name, 'qty': qty, 'price': price, 'date': str(date)})

    def sale(self, sell_qty, sell_date=datetime.date.today()):
        a = 0
        p = 0
        unit_val = 0
        new_price = 0
        newdict = (sorted(self.data_dict, key=lambda x: x['date']))

        for dt in newdict:
            a += dt['qty']
            p += dt['price']
            if sell_date > dt['date']:
                if sell_qty <= a:
                   unit_val = float(p / a)
                    new_price = unit_val * a
                    a -= sell_qty
                    self.data_dict.append({'product': product_obj.name, 'qty': a, 'price': new_price, 'date': str(sell_date)})
                    print("sold!")

            else:
                print("Sorry, not enough qty.\n")


C = Company()
PRODUCT_OBJ = Product()
PRODUCT_OBJ.add_product('Computer')

while True:

    option = int(input(" 1. You want to add stock of the product!\n2. Want to sell product?\n"))

    if option == 1:
        qty = int(input("Enter the qty of the product.\n"))
        price = float(input("Enter the price of the product.\n"))
        purchase_date = input("Enter purchase date.\n")
        C.purchase(PRODUCT_OBJ, qty, price, purchase_date)

    elif option == 2:
        qty = int(input("Enter the qty you wanna sell, pal!"))
        sale_date = input("Enter sell date.\n")
        C.sale(qty)
```

getting errors :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:/python/test.py", line 63, in <module>  C.sale(qty)
  File "G:/python/test.py", line 33, in sale if sell_date > dt['date']:
 TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'datetime.date' and 'str'
```

desired output :

```
[{'qty': 12, 'price': 2000.0, 'product': 'Computer', 'date': '2018-01-01'},
{'qty': 6, 'price': 1523.0, 'product': 'Computer', 'date': '2018-02-03'},
{'qty': 10, 'price': 1000.0, 'product': 'Computer', 'date': '2018-12-05'},
{'qty': 20, 'price': 2000.0, 'product': 'Computer', 'date': '2019-11-06'},
{'qty': 10, 'price': 1000.0, 'product': 'Computer', 'date': '2019-08-02'}
]
```

Comment: What errors are you getting? Some of the indentation in your code does not look right. For example, this line `self.name = name`.

Comment: @Munosphere yes , thats for product name 'computer' its for future modification, right now i am just looking for FIFO. other attributes for enhancement purpose buddy..

Comment: I mean the code can't even be run because of indentation error. Anyway, please include the errors that you are receiving and your desired output in question.

Comment: Immediately after pasting code into your question, select what you just pasted and either type Ctrl+K or click the `{}` button in the editor interface. That will automatically format the block of code so you won't introduce indentation errors while trying to fix it manually.

Answer (score 1):

@adrtam showed you how to fix the error you posted. But your code has serious issues. I won't fix everything, but here are a few hints:

- class `Supplier`: `add_supplier` should be `__init__`. You create a new supplier with: `s = Supplier("foo", "bar", "baz@baz", "no")`
- class `Product`: idem
- class `Company`:

  - should not inherit from `Product` and `Supplier` (a company IS A product and a supplier ? No)
  - misses an `__init__` method: `data_dict` is currently a class field, should be an instance field
- avoid names like `a`, `p`: always use significant names.
- in the desired output, there's no reason to set, after the sale, the date of the first row to '2018-01-01'
- prefer verbs to name your method (depends on the context): `sell` instead of `sale`.

Now, let's look at the `sell` method. I assume that this is a FIFO stock: you sell first the products that were purchased first.
Here's a simple idea:

- Iterate over the rows and sum the qty available.
- As soon as the qty is sufficient, exit of the loop
- Then remove the rows browsed and fix the qty of the last browsed row.

Example code (I assume that the data is always ordered by date: to enforce this, you may use a [priority queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html)):

```
data = [{'qty': 20, 'price': 2000.0, 'product': 'Computer', 'date': '2017-03-05'},
    {'qty': 22, 'price': 5000.0, 'product': 'Computer', 'date': '2017-11-11'},
    {'qty': 6, 'price': 1523.0, 'product': 'Computer', 'date': '2018-02-03'},
    {'qty': 10, 'price': 1000.0, 'product': 'Computer', 'date': '2018-12-05'},
    {'qty': 20, 'price': 2000.0, 'product': 'Computer', 'date': '2019-11-06'},
    {'qty': 10, 'price': 1000.0, 'product': 'Computer', 'date': '2019-08-02'}]

wanted = {'qty': 30, 'date': '2018-01-01'}

def sell(wanted):
    global data # NEVER do this: just for the example
    assert wanted['qty'] > 0
    qty = 0
    for i, row in enumerate(data):
        # too late!
        if row['date'] > wanted['date']:
            raise Exception("Sorry, not enough qty. Operation cancelled")

        qty += row['qty']
        # we have enough Computers!
        if qty >= wanted['qty']:
            break
    else: # loop completes normally
        raise Exception("Sorry, not enough qty. Operation cancelled")

    remaining_qty_in_last_row = qty-wanted['qty']
    # copy of the last row with a new quantity + the remaining rows
    data = [{**row, 'qty':remaining_qty_in_last_row}] + data[i+1:]
    print ("Sold!")

for wanted in [{'qty': 30, 'date': '2018-01-01'}, {'qty': 30, 'date': '2018-01-01'}]:
    try:
         sell(wanted)
    except e:
         print(e)
    print ("data", data)
```

That's just a sketch of the algorithm: you have to practice to extract the right design of classes and methods.

Answer (score 0):

Let's just fix the error you posted:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:/python/test.py", line 63, in <module>  C.sale(qty)
  File "G:/python/test.py", line 33, in sale if sell_date > dt['date']:
 TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'datetime.date' and 'str'
```

The issue is you have `sell_date` in a datetime object but the date you have in the dictionary is a string. You need to convert them to the same type in order to make the comparison work. Two ways to do it:

1. Make your datetime object a fixed-format string that can be compared:

   ```
   if sell_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") > dt['date']:
   ```
2. Parse the date string into datetime object:

   ```
   import datetime
   if sell_date > datetime.datetime.strptime(dt['date'], '%Y-%m-%d'):
   ```

Comment: Thank you , so how about the other dictionary part buddy ?

Comment: it is not so clear to me what you mean. But if you just want to get rid of all dict in the list with date less than your sell_date, use list comprehension: `data_dict = [x for x in data_dict if x['date'] > sell_date]`